# Looking for direct ship connection between Mainz and Lake Constance (Bodensee)

Tags: germany, switzerland, ships, rhine, lake-constance

I would like to visit [Kreuzlingen](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kreuzlingen), [Konstanz](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konstanz) and [the Napoleonmuseum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arenenberg). As they are all located at Lake Constance and I'm living in Mainz I think it's not a bad idea to spend some time and travel by ship. Is this possible? Are there direct ferries or cruises from Mainz to the lake?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To make it short, no this is not possible. One reason for that are the [Rhinefalls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhine_Falls) between Lace Constance and Basel. Ferries can not overcome these falls.

[image]

However, there are ships between Mainz and Basel, Basel to the Rhine falls, and [ships from the Rhine falls to Lake Constance.](http://www.rheinfall.ch/Rheinfall/anreise#schiff)

On Lake Constance itself, there are a [lot of ferries.](http://www.bodenseeschifffahrt.de/fahrplan4.html)

Comment: Can you give some references regarding the ships between Mainz, Basel and the Rheinfall?